# Shopify as a SAML Identity Provider for my app

Tags: shopify

I have an existing Shopify Store. I want the customers to be able to sign into my app (that is completely separate from the Shopify Store) with their existing Shopify account. My backend allows the SAML protocol.

I have found this resource: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/organization-settings/security/saml. But if I understand correctly, this is exactly the opposite direction, where customers can log into the Shopify Store with another identity provider.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use SSO, where customers would sign in to your App, and you'd then SSO them into your Shopify store. You have to have Plus plan for that. It works fine, the SSO.

Comment: Could you provide more information on this? What do you mean by customers sign into my app? Does that mean my customers need to create an account on my app first? This is exactly what I'm trying to avoid because I don't want them to have two accounts. I do have Shopify Plus.

Comment: It sounds more like if a customer is logged into Shopify (a fact you can check in Shopify), then you can allow them access to your App via an App Proxy call. That is the way. Check that pattern out. It works.

Comment: do you have any documentation or resources I should checkout? I'm a little lost and don't quite understand what you suggest me to do